# Correct Many to Many friends relationship for users

Tags: parse-platform

What is the correct way to relate users in parse to one another as friends?

I also want users to be able to query other users but not see all fields, like emails. Is there a way I can create a view on the users table with cloud code, and only return this to the client code?

I was thinking I can create a friends table that will have two columns with 2 pointers, 1 for each user.

thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 0):

> I was thinking I can create a friends table that will have two columns with 2 pointers, 1 for each user.

I'll do that too, with a status column to handle pending, blocked...etc

> I also want users to be able to query other users but not see all fields, like emails.

You have to add a privateData column on user with ACL restricted to owner only, which would contain private infos such as emails...etc